# angular ui-select2 compile all elements when add new element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ui-select2

Every time I add new value to ui-select2 input, it compiles all selections again.
how do I prevent that? I want to add a directive and that could be heavy.

thanks!

take a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/51TbAn4dYYCjmhK64I7H?p=preview) just add a new item as see all values are changing.

my input is inside a directive:

```
app.directive('optionChoices', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      option: '='
    },
    template: '<input ui-select2="colorChoices" ng-model="option.selections" style="width:200px">',
    controller: ['$scope', '$compile', function ($scope, $compile) {

    function Query(query) {
        var data = query.term !== ''?
        { results:[{id : query.term, value: '', text : query.term}] } :
        { results:[] };
        query.callback (data);
    }

    function colorFormat(state, container) {
        return (new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    }

    $scope.textChoices = {
        query: Query,
        initSelection: angular.noop,
        tags: []
    };
    $scope.colorChoices = angular.extend({}, $scope.textChoices, {
        formatSelection: colorFormat
    });
    }]
  };
});
```